# Product Extension attributes is not return when request from rest api

Tags: magento2, rest-api, extension-attributes

I have created an **extension attribute** for a product.

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
    <attribute code="product_options" type="Sample\Module\Api\Data\ProductOptionInterface" />
</extension_attributes>
```

So I am able to set `product_options` to the product.

But when I request using API

```
http://10.16.16.216/example/magento/rest/all/V1/products/mypsku
```

Then JSON response is no contained my extension attribute. `product_options`

My plugin

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
    <plugin name="set_product_options" type="Sample\Module\Plugin\Catalog\ProductOption"/>
</type>
```

ProductOption

Answer (score 0):

You need to use after plugin for Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface (afterGet and afterGetList function). For that use, di.xml and your custom plugin class for ProductInterface. Then in response of API, your custom extension attribute will be available.

Comment: afterGet method is not calling in my plugin.

Comment: Please paste code in your quesiton